# Qtp dynamic execution order

Tags: vbscript, frameworks, automation, qtp, hp-uft

So I have a keyword driven framework that executes on keywords.  In one of the functions I have a if element exist condition. Now if that element doesn't exist I want qtp to not execute the next 3 keyword functions following it. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Current answers show that it is quite unclear what you´re asking if you don´t provide a code sample (or other info) indicating why you cannot simply branch using `If`.

Answer (score 0):

You could a global variable that records the number of keywords that should be skipped.  When your element doesn't exist, you could set the skip count to 3.  In your framework that reads each keyword, you could first check the current skip count.  If it's 0, you execute the keyword normally.  Otherwise, you decrease the skip count by 1 and exit without executing that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not insert a conditional statement?

Therefore if the element exists, you can put the next 3 statements within the loop?  Else, do nothing.  Then have the code follow on as normal?

If you aren't comfortable in expert view, this shows how to do it in keyword view also:

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/conditional-loop-statements-qtp-tutorial-4/